# turnoff the display programmatically in android

Tags: android, screen-off

Is it possible to turn-off the display programmatically in android? I would like to have a button that when pressed switches the display off. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try doing the following:

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
mDPM.lockNow();
```

That will lock your phone (same as pressing the power/lock button) and thus turn of the screen.

Comment: If I am not wrong this needs a lot of `DeviceAdmin` stuff to be implemented and that requires a permission that can be used only by a system application.